# error c2259 'class': cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, class, vector, constructor, abstract

I have this problem with abstract classes and I looked up everywhere on the internet (including here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxt206sk.aspx), I asked friends, and I still didn't get an answer.

I have a class called 'RulePrvoider', and three more classes 'GlobalRuleProvider', 'UserRuleProvider', and 'OrgRuleProvider' that inherit from 'Rule Provider'. I also have another class called 'PacketFilter', and that's the class I have a problem with.

I found out that if I put the 'push_back' in comments, the program DOES compile, but I can't seem to figure out why.

This is the PacketFilter.h:

```
#ifndef _PACKETFILTER_H
#define _PACKETFILTER_H

#include <vector>
#include <set>

#include "OrgRuleProvider.h"
#include "GlobalRuleProvider.h"
#include "UserRuleProvider.h"
class PacketFilter
{
private:
    std::vector <RuleProvider>providers;
    string globalProvider;
    std::set <Rule>rules;
    void update();
public:
    PacketFilter(string globalProviderPath, string* orgProviderPath, string* userProviderPath);
    bool filter(string srcIP, string srcPort, string dstIP, string dstPort, string protocol);
};
#endif
```

and this is the packetFilter constructor (that's where I have the problems):

```
#include "PacketFilter.h"

PacketFilter::PacketFilter(string globalProviderPath, string* orgProviderPath, string* userProviderPath)
{
    int i;
    RuleProvider* rProv;
    try{
        rProv = new GlobalRuleProvider(globalProviderPath);
    }
    catch (int e){
        std::cout << "exception number " << e << std::endl;
    }
    providers.push_back(*rProv);
    for (i = 0; i <orgProviderPath->size(); i++)
    {
        rProv = new OrgRuleProvider(orgProviderPath[i]);
        providers.push_back(*rProv);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < userProviderPath->size(); i++)
    {
        rProv = new UserRuleProvider(userProviderPath[i]);
        providers.push_back(*rProv);
    }
}
```

I will be VERY glad and grateful if someone finds out the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are allocating with `new` then pushing back a copy, leaking memory. If you want virtual behavior, you should keep *pointers* and not objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do

```
std::vector <RuleProvider> providers;
```

`RuleProvider` is the abstract class. You can't instantiate abstract objects.

You need to do

```
std::vector <RuleProvider*> providers;
```

Pointers are a different story--you can *point* to abstract types, because the actual object itself will be a subclass of `RuleProvider`, not the abstract base class.

When you `push_back` onto the vector, push the pointers you made with `new`; don't dereference them with `*`.

When you are done with the `vector` you will need to remember to `delete` all the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `providers` is a `std::vector <RuleProvider>`. When you `push_back` an object of a concrete subclass of `RuleProvider`, you first create a new `RuleProvider` with a copy constructor. But if `RuleProvider` is an abstract class, it leads to an error. The rule is that you should never use subclasses with std containers. If you need that, you could instead use a `std::vector <RuleProvider *>`.